# laravel - configurar phpstorm

Tags: laravel

Buenas estoy trabajando en phpstorm, pero me he dado cuenta que mientras desarrollo el proyecto el editor de codigo me marca como una especie de error ciertas variables. Alguna forma de solucionarlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sólo ve a **Settings->Inspections->Spelling** y desactiva **Typo**

Answer (score 1):

Estas variables las marca porque no las encuentra en el diccionario. Si usas nombres de variables en español instala un diccionario de español y dejará de marcarlas como errores.

En Jetbrains puedes descargar el plugin con diccionario incluido
[Plugin + diccionario](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7851-spell-checker-spanish-dictionary)